# Webservice based WPF application

Tags: wpf, web-services

I want to create a simple WPF application that uses a asmx webservice to communicate with a database (WPF > Webservice > LINQ2SQL > SQL DB).

The WPF will need to both consume and update data in the database.

Does anybody have any guides, examples or best practices to follow?

Comment: Why would there be any "best practices"? There's nothing special about WPF that would make consuming a web service from WPF any different from any other kind of application. Just use "Add Service Reference" just like any other kind of application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the MVVM pattern to get the most stability out of this.  Check out my blog for some MVVM examples.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/category/mvvm/

Also check this out.

http://wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com/